# How do I go about testing anonymous functions in sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I'm new to node.js. I have an abstracted piece of logic that I'd like to write a unit test for. I have this piece of code, in let's say `foo.js`, which looks like:

```
'use strict';

const Bar = require('bar.js');

const abstractOutThisLogic = (functionInBar) => async (...args) =>
  functionInBar(...args).catch((err) => {
    throw new Error(err.message, {
      statusCode: err.status
    });
  });

module.exports = {
  create: abstractOutThisLogic(Bar.createThisThing),
  delete: abstractOutThisLogic(Bar.deleteThisThing)
};
```

It's basically an abstracted piece of logic to invoke functions in `bar.js`. Instead of having different functions for `createThisThing` and `deleteThisThing`, I want to have one abstracted function which removes all the duplicate code that these functions might have.

The functions in `bar.js` look like this:

```
exports.createThisThing = async (payload) => {
  const resp = await externalApi.createThisThing(payload);
  return resp;
};

exports.deleteThisThing = async (payload) => {
  const resp = await externalApi.deleteThisThing(payload);
  return resp;
};
```

Now, I'm trying to write a unit test to test whether these functions in `bar.js` are invoked correctly (and how many times it was called etc) by the abstracted function in `foo.js`.

My unit test in `foo.test.js` looks like:

```
it('is trying to test this anonymous function in foo.js', async () => {
  const payload = {
    id: 'foo',
    value: 'baz'
  }

  const barFnSpy = Sinon.spy(Bar.createThisThing);
  await Foo.create(payload);

  assert(barFnSpy.calledWith(payload));
});
```

It appears to me that `sinon` is having a hard time stubbing/spying on this anonymous function call in `foo.js`. How can I go about testing the functionality of this abstracted function in `foo.js` through sinon?

Comment: What you are trying to do is impossible. You've already run `abstractOutThisLogic` as the code is parsed and assigned their results to `create` and `delete` . There's nothing to be stubbed. suddjian's suggestion is my suggestion, you are really trying to test that `abstractOutThisLogic` can catch errors thrown by functions passed into it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That definitely makes a lot of sense and I'll follow what suddjian suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You should test your `abstractOutThisLogic` function and your `Bar.createThisThing` function separately.

Pass stub functions to your `abstractOutThisLogic` function which behave predictably, and you can assert things like how many times the stub was called, the details of the error that gets thrown if the wrapped function throws, etc.

```js
describe("abstracted logic", () => {
  it("should handle errors", () => {
    const stub = sinon.stub().throws()
    expect(abstractOutThisLogic(stub)).toThrow()
  })
})
```

Then write a separate set of tests asserting behavior of the `Bar` functions, without being wrapped by `abstractOutThisLogic`.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for answering and clarifying. As a follow-up, how can I import `abstractOutThisLogic` function into my test file? Since it is a property. I don't think I'll be able to run `expect(Foo.abstractOutThisLogic(stub)).toThrow()` right? I'm exposing the wrapped functions by module exports.

Comment: Who downvoted this? Without any reason? @sachinmurali92 suddjian is suggesting you modify your code to `export const abstractOutThisLogic` so it can be tested.